# Django: timezone.now vs timezone.now()

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am in the process of upgrading my project from Django 1.8.2 to 1.9.7 and I'm getting this warning:

```
WARNINGS:
my_app.my_model.date_available: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. 
If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now
```

Here's the line from my_app/models.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone
...
class my_model(models.Model):
    ...
    datetime_released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() )
```

If I remove the parentheses and instead use:

```
datetime_released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now )
```

The Django warning goes away.  What's the difference between the two?

---

In another area of my project I am using timezone.now() in a queryset filter:

```
def date_available(self):
        return self.filter(date_available__lte = timezone.now())
```

Here, if I remove the parentheses, an error is thrown:

`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

---

I can get both of these two work by adding/removing the parenthesis as required, but what is the difference between `timezone.now()` and `timezone.now` and why do they cause warnings/errors in these cases?

Comment: type(now()) reruns a datetime object. type(now)  reruns the method now

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In python everything is an object, including functions. This means you can affect a function to a variable:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> foo = timezone.now
>>> foo
<function django.utils.timezone.now>
>>> foo()
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 7, 9, 11, 6, 489063)
```

A function is a callable object:

```
>>> callable(foo)
True
>>> callable(foo())
False
```

When `default` receives a callable, the callable is called each time a default value is requested.

On the other hand, when you call `timezone.now()` prior to setting `default`, the value is given and fixed. As a reminder, the following line is executed only once at server start up, since it is a class attribute:

```
    datetime_released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

and thus `timezone.now()` is executed only once. Passing a callable `timezone.now` makes it possible to recalculate the value whenever it needs to be.

Comment: I don't understand still. Will `timezone.now()` still work or should I used just: `timezone.now` ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "work". Using `models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())` will "work" but you're setting the default value to the time the server was started.

Comment: So `timezone.now` will update to today when making the model and will not update after that?

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that `timezone.now` is a callable that gets executed at runtime, while `timezone.now()` returns the output of that function.

For the `models.DateTimeField`, you need to use the callable. Better still, just set [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) which does this for you:

```
datetime_released = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The filter on the other hand does not accept a callable - it requires a value. Hence you must evaluate `timezone.now()` when passing this as an argument to the filter.

Comment: The thing worth mentioning here is that when you pass `timezone.now()`, you're effectively passing the output of that function at the time when django boots up (this is when it gets evaluated), while when you pass `timezone.now` you're passing the function object that gets lazily evaluated by django.

Comment: What if you want to have a model that has a creation timestamp? Would the `timezone.now()` be better in that case than `timezone.now`, which would end up being reevaluated every so often?

Answer (score 2):

In `self.filter(date_available__lte = timezone.now())` you want to make a query to the DB based on the current time. So you need it in string format.

In `datetime_released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` you want default to be current time. So you cannot have a string there. Instead you provide a function which can return current time.

Answer (score 1):

now()  gets executed when the model is loaded and returns a datetime object / time string at loading. (hence the Django warning!) 
(The model file if fully executed when the server starts)

now  will pass on the now method, and will get executed only when the class/model gets instantiated, creating the time stamp at the right time (the correct way, and what most people are trying to achieve).

In the filter example, it only gets called when the filter function is called.
if you don't executed (now())  and will feed the method, and will never generate the required datetime object. (error, expected a string, got, something else)

Answer (score 1):

timezone.now() returns the current timestamp when when model is loaded. On the other hand, timezone.now is passed as an argument to the function and it is called whenever the object is created (on class instantiation)

in the following code

```
def date_available(self):
    return self.filter(date_available__lte = timezone.now())
```

the function date_availabe needs a function string to **parse as a function** when it returns self.filter.