# How to use timedelta with timezone.now as default?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django models, How to increment the date field using `timezone.now`?

**working:**

```
end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=365))
```

**Not Working**

```
end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now + timezone.timedelta(days=365))
```

I think `timezone.now` is a function which runs every time when the object is created. so that error occurs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a function:

```
def f():
   return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=365)
...
end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=f)
```

The current time in that timezone is the added with the timedelta anytime a new `end_date` is created by default:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> def f():
...    return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=365)
... 
>>> f()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 25, 19, 42, 49, 761389, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> f()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 25, 19, 43, 2, 953158, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Sample run with Django:

```
In [1]: from testapp import models

In [2]: models.Test.objects.create().date_added
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 25, 20, 5, 28, 316214, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [3]: models.Test.objects.create().date_added
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 25, 20, 5, 33, 114624, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: But While I run django makemigrations I got `ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda`

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian I've updated. lambdas are not serializable, I didn't keep that in mind.

Comment: Sorry... While using timezone.now(), time is not set at runtime

Comment: see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237777/django-timezone-now-vs-timezone-now

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian no, that's different. You're not passing `timezone.now()` directly, in which it gets calls and there's constant value at object creation. Here, the `timezone.now` is called when the function is called which creates a new value everytime. You can easily check this by calling the function repeatedly.

Comment: I am  confused. Here What I tried.  I opened `python manage.py shell`.  Multiple times I created object through `ModelName.objects.create()` datetime is same.  But once i quit the shell and reopen and recreated object, time get changed.

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian Did you check the seconds/microseconds for each of the instances? I guess you're creating all the objects within the same minute.

Comment: yup. I checked with microseconds. No Moses I create with significant interval. (Last 5 objects time: 2018-06-26 01:10:44.148109) Can u pls check with django models ?

Comment: Do a quick check for what happens in your shell when the `default=timezone.now`. Is the behavior different?

Comment: default just return a  function. Every time I call default, time get changed

Comment: OMG.. Really sorry Moses. I wrote `default=f with default=f()`. Extremely Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. Thanks a lot Moses Koledoye.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to use the `post_save` signal. Import it with
`from django.db.models.signals import post_save` and then create a handler function like this:

```
def handler_function(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if sender == YourModel and created:
        instance.end_date = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=365)
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(handler_function, sender=YourModel)
```

This will work for sure, I hope this also applies to your case. Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: The factory function should only handle the default case, not assign a fixed date for every object.

Comment: Academically asking, can you give me an example of that? As I'm not sure I understand the difference in this case

Comment: When you set a non-default `end_date` on the model object, it gets overwritten by this procedure in your `post_save`, which is not the case with `default=...` in the model field.

Comment: Yes, the usage of this method connected with the `post_save` signal is intended to be used without a default in the model definition.