# Python-django typeerror: expected string or bytes-like object error -- object.save()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

**I'm learning django-orm my code is this:**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Author(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField() 
class Book(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, null=True)
```

**and I'm creating a shell then I'm instantiation objects like this:**

```
python manage.py shell
   >> from books.models import Author,Book 
   >> Author.objects.all()
   >> from django.utils import timezone
   >> author = Author(name="Victor Hugo",created = timezone.now) 
   >> author.save()
```

**But when i try to .save() my objects it's giving this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save     
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1276, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1218, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1431, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1410, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1270, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1371, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**Any help? What I'm supposed to do? I'm pretty new here and this is my first question**

Answer (score 1):

The issue is depicted on this line of the error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1371, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

It indicates that your field for your datetime (when you created an Author object with `timezone.now`) was invalid.

This is because you didn't call it correctly. Your shell should show this:

```
python manage.py shell
   >> from books.models import Author,Book 
   >> Author.objects.all()
   >> from django.utils import timezone
   >> author = Author(name="Victor Hugo",created = timezone.now()) 
   >> author.save()
```

Notice the change in `timezone.now` to `timezone.now()`.

[Here's a link to the reasoning behind the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237777/django-timezone-now-vs-timezone-now)

Comment: Omg -.-  Thank you so much!